# R : Error looping in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use a loop to simplify a `ggplot`command, but it only assigns the last part of the loop to my `ggplot` object.

```
plot.test = ggplot(data = plot.df, aes(x = xvariable)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = yvariable)) 

for (i in 1:6){
  plot.test = plot.test + geom_point(aes(y = ypoints[i], x = xpoints[i])) 
}
```

So, the problem is, that after running the loop, `plot.test` does only contain the original line and the last point from the loop, i.e. point (`x[6],y[6]`)

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want to do that?

Is

```
ggplot( data = plot.df, aes( x = xvariable, y = yvariable ) ) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point( data = plot.df[1:6,], aes( y = ypoints, x = xpoints ) )
```

what you are looking for?

**Edit**:

In my original answer I wrote that *You cannot add multiple geometric objects of the same type to one `ggplot`*. This is obviously wrong as the following example states:

```
dt <- data.frame( x = rnorm(1:10), y = rnorm(1:10) )
ggplot( mapping = aes( x = x, y = y ) ) +
  geom_point( data = dt[1:5,] ) +
  geom_point( data = dt[6:10,] )
```

However I have really difficulties to think of an example where this would be necessary. From my experience I would always presume that the reason for using two times the same geom in the same plot is a result of a bad data model.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dataset to work with.

```
plot.df <- data.frame(xvariable=1:6, yvariable=1:6+rnorm(6,0,0.3), xpoints=1:6+rnorm(6,0,0.1), ypoints=1:6+rnorm(6,0,0.1))
```

It IS possible to add multiple geometric objects of the same type to one ggplot. For example:

```
ggplot(data = plot.df, aes(x = xvariable)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = yvariable)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=ypoints[1], x=xpoints[1])) +
  geom_point(aes(y=ypoints[2], x=xpoints[2])) +
  geom_point(aes(y=ypoints[3], x=xpoints[3])) +
  geom_point(aes(y=ypoints[4], x=xpoints[4])) +
  geom_point(aes(y=ypoints[5], x=xpoints[5])) +
  geom_point(aes(y=ypoints[6], x=xpoints[6]))
```

But that's a pain, and you're rightly seeking to avoid that sort of code replication. The answer depends on what you're looking for. Different formatting for each point? Try this:

```
ggplot(data = plot.df, aes(x = xvariable)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = yvariable)) +
  geom_point(data=transform(plot.df, pointsID=as.factor(1:6)), 
             aes(y=ypoints, x=xpoints, color=pointsID))
```

You can alter the colors (or choices for other formatting parameters) through calls to `scale_colour_discrete` and related ggplot components.

PS - Your original strategy failed because ggplot waits until print time to evaluate arguments such as the `i` in `xpoints[i]`; even though you see 1 point, you're actually plotting 6 of the same point right on top of one another.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do. I restructured my data already by realizing geom_point can take on whole dataframes of x,y coordinates based on the answer above. But checked this , and works as well.

Answer (score 1):

While reworking the data structure to avoid loops like this is the better answer, sometimes you really need to evaluate the expression immediately instead of closing over a variable and evaluating the expression later.  You can use ggplot2's [aes_string()](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes_string.html) to do just that:

```
plot.test = ggplot(data = plot.df, aes(x = xvariable)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = yvariable)) 

for (i in 1:6){
  plot.test = plot.test + geom_point(aes_string(y = ypoints[i], x = xpoints[i])) 
}
```

In this case you're effectively hardcoding the point values.  That is, it's equivalent to:

```
  plot.test = plot.test + geom_point(aes(y = 2, x = 3))
```

You can also hardcode only the index, and still dynamically refer to whatever is in ypoints and xpoints at a later time:

```
  plot.test = plot.test + geom_point(aes_string(y = paste0("ypoints[", i, "]"), x = paste0("xpoints[", i, "]")))
```

This is ugly and unwieldy and a bit of a hack, but it works and is sometimes just what you need if you can't liberally reorganize the data structure for whatever reason.